# DRY approaches for displaying fields in a ListView with custom [exclude]

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am writing a generic template that I can use across all my models that require a `ListView`.

To do this, I know I can simply create a generic table in my template with a `for` loop over the `object_list`, but as each model is different I can't capture all the fields this way.

Instead I have created a (abstract) method that each model inherits, which produces a list of fields, names and values:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def get_display_fields(self, exclude_fields=[], adminonly_fields=[]):
        """Returns a list of all field names on the instance."""
        fields = []
        for f in self._meta.fields:

            fname = f.name

            # resolve picklists/choices, with get_xyz_display() function
            get_choice = 'get_' + fname + '_display'
            if hasattr(self, get_choice):
                value = getattr(self, get_choice)()
            else:
                try:
                    value = getattr(self, fname)
                except AttributeError:
                    value = None

            if f.editable and f.name not in (exclude_fields or adminonly_fields):

                fields.append(
                    {
                        'label': f.verbose_name,
                        'name': f.name,
                        'help_text': f.help_text,
                        'value': value,
                    }
                )

        return fields
```

I can then use this in my template which works universally across any model:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {% for f in obj.get_display_fields %}
        <p>{{f.label}}</p>
        <p>{{f.name}}</p>
        <p>{{f.value}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Where I am stuck, is I want to allow some customisation of the `exclude_fields` and `adminonly_fields` in the view (which is on the model method). For example:

```
class MyGenericView(ListView):
    exclude_fields = ['field1', 'field2']
    adminonly_fields = ['field3',]
```

How can I pass these lists to `get_display_fields`?. I know I can just write them into the model method, but that defeats the point of this DRY approach. Can I append it to/modify the queryset somehow?

I don't want to use `editable=False` as I want to allow each view that subclasses `MyGenericView` to provide `excluded_fields` as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) that takes an argument. You will need to use the `{% load %}` tag to make it available.

It's important that you use a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) so that you can pass multiple arguments from your view.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_display_fields(obj, adminonly_fields=[], excluded_fields=[]):
    if hasattr(obj, 'get_display_fields')
        return obj.get_display_fields(adminonly_fields, excluded_fields)
    return []
```

Pass `adminonly_fields` and `excluded_fields` as [extra context data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) in your view so it can be used with your template tag.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['adminonly_fields'] = self.adminonly_fields
    context['excluded_fields'] = self.excluded_fields
    return context
```

Then in your template.

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {% get_display_fields obj adminonly_fields excluded_fields as display_fields %}
    {% for f in display_fields %}
        <p>{{f.label}}</p>
        <p>{{f.name}}</p>
        <p>{{f.value}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It would appear that `{% get_display_fields obj adminonly_fields excluded_fields as display_fields %}` only passes one variable, 'adminonly_fields'?

Comment: If you read the documentation on simple tags you'll see that it can take any number of positional and keyword arguments. If your code is copy/pasted from your OP then it's possible the error is in the naming of your keyword arguments in the `get_display_fields` method... `exclude_fields` instead of `excluded_fields`?